# Как читать условие с txt файла

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Это то, что находится в txt

```
processName == "taskhost" || processName == "services" 
                || processName == "svchost" || processName == "csrss" 
                || processName == "idle" || processName == "powershell" 
                || processName == "System" || processName == "webview2" 
                || processName == "rundll32" || processName == "Rtk" 
                || processName == "Gamebar" || processName == "RuntimeBroker"
```

Вот так выглядит код, хочу чтобы юзер мог сам добавлять в txt свои процессы, то есть вместо

```
private bool IsSystemProcess(Process process)
{
    string processName = process.ProcessName;


    // Добавьте сюда другие системные процессы, которые нужно исключить
    if (processName == "taskhost" || processName == "services"
        || processName == "svchost" || processName == "csrss"
        || processName == "idle" || processName == "powershell"
        || processName == "System" || processName == "webview2"
        || processName == "rundll32" || processName == "Rtk"
        || processName == "Gamebar" || processName == "RuntimeBroker")
    {
        return true;  // Процесс является запрещенным
    }

    return false;
}
```

было типо этого if('Текстовый документ')

Comment: Смотрите в сторону `json`, `ini` или `config` файлов.

Comment: а как точнее будет выглядеть код? нужны библиотеки какие нибудь?

Comment: Уберите лишнее, получите просто список процессов, разделите их каким либо символом, например, запятой, получите `taskhost, services, svchost, ...`, это все и пишите в файл, ну а затем просто `var result = File.ReadAllText("...").Split(',');`, готово, у вас список процессов из файла, ну а условие переписываете на `return result.Contains(processName);`, готово. Как сказали выше, JSON и др. форматы это хороший вариант, но если вам нужно что-то больше, чем просто список слов через запятую.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Советую попробовать JSON.

```
using System.Text.Json;
```

Берём массив, например такой

```cs
string[] processNames = new[] { "taskhost", "services", "svchost", "csrss" };
```

Сериализуем в файл

```
File.WriteAllText("file.json", JsonSerializer.Serialize(processNames));
```

Получаем файл с таким содержимым

```json
["taskhost","services","svchost","csrss"]
```

Далее файл можно загрузить

```cs
string text = File.ReadAllText("file.json");
string[] names = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(text);
```

Теперь ваш метод можно упростить до такого

```cs
private bool IsSystemProcess(Process process)
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText("file.json");
    string[] names = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(text);

    string processName = process.ProcessName;

    return names.Contains(processName);
    // или так
    // return Array.IndexOf(names, processName) >= 0;
}
```

Теперь, если хотите, можете в файл руками дописывать список, когда угодно, в кавычках через запятую.

---

Кстати, JSON можно сохранить с форматированием

```cs
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
File.WriteAllText("file.json", JsonSerializer.Serialize(processNames, options));
```

Тогда файл получится такой

```json
[
  "taskhost",
  "services",
  "svchost",
  "csrss"
]
```

Вместо массива можно использовать список `List<string>`, например, если вы хотите добавлять или удалять элементы прямо в коде, работать с JSON оно будет точно так же.